# Manipute with Razor dynamic javascript hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

The **#refrigeratorDelete** is a hyperlink (a-tag) I can have multiple refrigerators. Depending on the number of refrigerators I have to generate/manipulate the hyperlinks id and merge it with the unique refrigerator id. But the variable i is unknown inside the [].

How can I fix that?

```
 $(function () {

     for (var i = 0; i < @(Model.Refrigerators.Count()); i++) {

                $('#refrigeratorDelete@(Model.Refrigerators.ToList()[i]).on('click', function () {

                    // do stuff on single refrigerator
                });
            } 

});
```

UPDATE

```
 @foreach (var refrigerator in Model.Refrigerators)
                    {
                        <li>    
                            <a id="refrigeratorDelete(@refrigerator.RefrigeratorId)" href="#">delete</a>
                        </li>
                    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
 $('#refrigeratorDelete@(Model.RefrigeratorId)').on('click', function () {
            var title = 'title';
            var warningMessage = 'message';

            ShowYesNoWarningDialog(title, warningMessage, function () {
            // When OK/YES button is clicked call the server side action:
                document.location.href = '@(MVC.Devices.Refrigerator.Delete(Model.RefrigeratorId).Result.ToHRefUrl())';
            });
        });
```

Explanation: When someone clicks on the delete link a delete dialog opens with Yes/No button. If no is clicked the dialog closes. If yes is clicked the closes too but the ShowYesNoWarningDialog executes now the document.location.href = ... code which goes to the server. Inside the MVC...Delete action I can not pass a client side id because the context is unknown.

The Delete action MUST be a NON-AJAX call as the customer wants it!

Comment: I have mixed feelings right now. I don't know if I should like or not what you're attempting there. I can, however, say that it won't work. Consider adding additional data using `data-` attributes and binding a `click` event on a class, set on all the links.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do. The name `refrigeratorDelete` suggests your trying to delete something so it should definitely not be a hyperlink (your need to do a POST) and it makes even less sense since you can only have one element with `id="refrigeratorDelete"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think he's trying to generate unique ids (or to bind unique ids to `click` events). That being said, maybe he's deleting using AJAX.

Comment: @AndreiV YOU are right. I try to delete with ajax. I do and can not change my delete to a post form...I have to use this code as it is! I just ask you to help me not more. I don`t need architects - now -

Comment: @Pascal, You certainly can use _"this code as it is"_ - it wont work. Are you wanting to click on a link use ajax to post the ID of the `Refrigerator` to the controller method?

Comment: If you post your HTML where the links get generated, we could come up with a better solution. The way you are mixing Razor and JavaScript simply does not work.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes that is what I want. It worked for ONE refrigerator. Now I have to for-loop that creation of the dynamic ids.

Comment: AS @AndreiV noted, you need to show view where your generating the links. The best way to solve this is to add a `data-` attribute to the link with the ID value, and give the link a class name, then handle the click event and retrieve the ID from the `data-` attribute

Comment: but the handling of the click event with jquery is the problem I have... see above my code.

Comment: @Pascal, If you show your view, we can give you the solution

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did as you said and updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view give each link a class name and add the ID property of the `Refrigerator` as a `data-` attribute

```
@foreach (var refrigerator in Model.Refrigerators)
{
  <li>    
    <a href="#" class="delete" data-id="@refrigerator.RefrigeratorId">delete</a>
  </li>
}
```

Then in the script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Delete", "controllerName")';
$('.delete').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id'); // get the ID of the refrigerator
  var li = $(this).closest('li'); // in case you want to delete the li element
  $.post(url, { id: id }, function(response) {
    // if successful, use li.remove(); to remove the element
  });
});
```

the above script assumes you have a method similar to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int ID)
{
  // delete the refrigerator based on its ID
  return Json(true); // indicate success?
}
```

Comment: Sorry Stephen and others. I updated my post again. I forgot some important code last time. I do not think your solution will work with my fully pasted code. I need the razors model refrigeratorId => '@(MVC.Devices.Refrigerator.Delete(Model.RefrigeratorId).Result.ToHRefUrl())';

Comment: I also added an explanation now what happens.

Comment: The Delete action itself MUST be a NON-AJAX call as the customer wants it! I can not change that. He wants a page-load behavior.

Comment: I marked it as solution because it technically works... internally we changed stuff and do it different now :-)

Comment: @Pascal, Further to your edit, your should **never** use a GET method to delete an item. In your loop, render a `@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "yourController", new { id = refrigerator.RefrigeratorId }) { <input type="submit" value="delete" /> }`. If your want your submit button to look like a link, then style it using css.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class to the delete button:

```
 @foreach (var refrigerator in Model.Refrigerators)
     {
         <li>
             <a id="refrigeratorDelete(@refrigerator.RefrigeratorId)" class="my-delete-btn" href="#">delete</a>
         </li>
     }
```

and us it when you attach onclick events like that:

```
$(function () {
    $('.my-delete-btn').on('click', function () {
        var currentId = this.id;
        // do stuff on single refrigerator
    });
});
```